# Install Intel driver on Oracle Linux

Tags: drivers, wifi-driver, oracle-linux

I have in virtualbox fresh install of Oracle Linux. I would like to connect to internet but missing wifi adapter. My kernel `4.18.0-147.el8.x86-64` lsmod prints that I have loaded iwlwifi.

`lspci | grep net`
outputs this card
`Intel Corporation 82540EM`

How can get my wifi adapter works? Its needed for study purposes on DBA oracle.

Comment: Which operating system you are using as base and what version of Virtual box are you running? Please specify.

Comment: Linux Mint is base host system

Comment: Why not just install kernel headers?

Comment: yeah you can either install `linux-headers` or `linux-headers-lts` as per your kernel.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't make sense.
Typically your host system uses the Wifi adapter to connect.
And it shares it network connection with the VM.
The VM sees a normal (Wired) ethernet adapter with a 10.x.x.x ip-address. The VirtualBox software will NAT that onto the real ip-address that the host uses.
At no point in that scenario does the guest-OS need Wifi drivers. In fact: The guest doesn't even know it is on Wifi.

It is possible to have the guest use the Wifi adapter directly but that usually involves a great deal off fidling and the host system can't use the Wifi adapter simultaneously in that case.